# Tuple objectt is not callable

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

trying to run the below code and receiving the 'tuple' object is not callable error. Any help would be appreciated!

```
drug_list = sum_df.index.tolist()
count = (study.groupby(["Drug Regimen"]) ["Age_months"].count()).tolist()
#list
#count

x_axis = np.arange(len(count))
x_axis = drug_list
plt.figure(figsize=(10,3))
plt.bar(x_axis, count, color="b", alpha = 0.5, align="center")
plt.title ("Drug Regimen Timepoints")
plt.xlabel("Drug Regimen")
plt.ylabel("Total Count")


TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_4864/2917130576.py in <module>
      8 x_axis = drug_list
      9 plt.figure(figsize=(10,3))
---> 10 plt.bar(x_axis, count, color="b", alpha = 0.5, align="center")
     11 plt.title ("Drug Regimen Timepoints")
     12 plt.xlabel("Drug Regimen")

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Comment: I might not be correct, but `plt.bar` is a tuple, I think. You should put `print(plt.bar)` behind the line that causes the error.

Comment: hmm, just tried that but didn't work. Thank you for the quick response though!

Comment: yeah, it's really bizarre because `pyplot.bar` is a plotting function, but your code is suggesting it's actually a tuple. Can you tell us what you get when you type `plt.bar` in your console after the exception? Is there code you didn't mention where you did something like `plt.bar = (1,2)`?

Comment: this is the first time plt.bar is being used in the code. My other code is just some calculations.

Comment: How did you import plt? Try `print(plt)` or `type(plt)` - somewhere along the ways plt is being redefined would be my guess. It would help if you published a complete (minimal) code example. I suspect you've left out the part where the problem lies.

Comment: Isn't x_axis set to multi-index?

Comment: What did `print(plt.bar)` show when you tried it?

Comment: Assuming plt is effectively matplotlib.pyplot then bar() is a function. It's possible that the values you're passing as the first two parameters may not be of appropriate types. Try printing them out

Comment: Did you (in earlier code) assign some value to `plt.bar`? Something like `plt.bar = ...`?

Comment: Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Always provide a complete [mre] with **code, data, errors, current output, and expected output**, as **[formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. If relevant, only plot images are okay.

Comment: When I printed plt.bar it gave me the following <function bar at 0x0000024411474670> sorry, I am really new to all of this. I also tried the type and came out as a module.

Comment: You need to print x_axis and count before calling plt.bar